# mapbox.js: creating offline-capable map with local tiles

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm about to develop a map with mapbox.js which has to work offline showing a local tileset. I'm using this code to implement my map:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map');
            var trailsLayer = L.tileLayer('../tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                minZoom: 9,
                maxZoom: 16,
                maxNativeZoom: 15,
                attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://www.trails.de">www.trails.de</a>, &#169; 2014 by Trails!. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/">ODBL</a>.'
        }).addTo(map);
```

I'm writing my code with Adobe Brackets editor and the map works well on the live Chrome Browser and also when I uploadw it on a server. But the map tiles won't show up when I just open the HTML-file locally from within my folder.
Thank you very much for any suggestion!

Comment: When you open the JavaScript console in your browser, does it give you any errors?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the Mapbox API is using XMLHttpRequests to access some of the local data. Most browsers do not allow this, since it would allow the page to read any file on your machine.

This should show an error in the JavaScript console.